# Is it always possible to decompose the space $\Bbb{C}^n$ to direct sum of invariant eigenspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A$ is $n\times n$ matrix over the complex field. Is it always possible to decompose the space $\Bbb{C}^n$ to direct sum of the invariant eigenspaces , or is it possible if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: In your class, have you already covered the Jordan canonical form? Basically, the theory behind it tells you all you need to know. The general answer to your question is that you are correct, it's possible if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable. If it's not, there is still a way do decompose $\mathbb C^n$, but not as the sum of eigenspaces, but something else, namely the generalized eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I learned Jordan canonical form. What does it mean generalized eigenvectors of A? What is the direct sum?

Comment: You said you learned Jordan canonical form. The fact that you are asking me what generalized eigenvectors are makes me doubdt you really did. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Generalized_eigenvectors

Answer (score 2):

With $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ we have $A^2=0$, hence for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of$A$ we must have $\lambda^2=0$, i.e. $\lambda=0$. On the other hand the eigenspace of $\lambda=0$ is certainly not all of $\mathbb C^2$. Hence this $A$ does not allow a direct sum decomposition into eigenspaces.